# How to extract if any digit present from list of matched word in text

Tags: python, regex

```
final_str = 'hello your total sale Fare Rs 741 your bill pls'
r = re.compile(r'\bSale\b|\bFare\b|\fare\b|\bRs\b', flags=re.I | re.X)
p=r.findall(final_str)
lis_con = p
matched = ''.join(lis_con)
res = final_str 
list_of_words = res.split()
gotdata = list_of_words[list_of_words.index(lis_con[0]) + 1]
print(gotdata)
```

So far I have tried this but not reaching the result, output expectation is it should check all list of words present in the dictionary and its return digit, for example, it matches Sale, Fare, Rs So its return the next word but I want to return the only digit in my case it should return 45. I think I need to check isDigit() any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'\b(?:Sale|Fare|Rs)\s+(\d+)', final_str, re.I)`. See https://ideone.com/FV6aXE

Comment: @Wiktor Please tell me what changes I have to do in your code if I want to extract if I had 2,804.00 digits

Comment: See https://ideone.com/OnuHaj

Comment: Yes It's Exactly working as my expectation Thanks for your valuable response and time

Comment: "Hello, your bill total 5 sale Fare Rs 7.41 your ride fare 5,545.00" if any one of the words matched it should return either 7.41 or 5,545.00 not 5 can you please tell me what changes I have to do in your code @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: It still [works](https://regex101.com/r/meZXM2/1).

Comment: No I mean I don't want to print 5 from the text I want to ignore single-digit number from the text it should print only 7.41 or 5,545.00

Comment: [It does not match `5`](https://regex101.com/r/meZXM2/1).

Comment: Sorry i have forgot to update my string here it is \b(?:|total|Sale|Fare|Rs)\s+(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?)

Comment: When you added `|` after `?:` you made the whole group optional. If you do not want to match single digit numbers, you will have to use something like `\b(?:(?:total|Sale|Fare|Rs)\s+)?((?:\d+(?:,\d+)+(?:\.\d+)?|\d{2,})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\b(?:Sale|Fare|Rs)\s+(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sDE4du/1). Details:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:Sale|Fare|Rs)` - `Sale`, `Fare` or `Rs` strings
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 1: one or more digits, then zero or more repetitions of a comma and one or more digits, and then an optional occurrence of a dot and one or more digits.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/OnuHaj):

```py
import re
final_str = 'hello your total sale Fare Rs 741 your bill pls and Sale 2,804.00'
r = re.compile(r'\b(?:Sale|Fare|Rs)\s+(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?)', flags=re.I)
gotdata = r.findall(final_str)
print(gotdata)
# => ['741', '2,804.00']
```